# Eclipse Juno, need root access everytime I change the configuration

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I am trying to install eclipse Juno on 12.04. I did all the things instructed in [this link](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/07/install-eclipse-juno-and-android-sdk-on-ubuntu/).

But whenever I install any new software (Say CDT or Pydev) on Eclipse, the new softwares are gone upon opening the Eclipse app again. I then have to open Eclipse again with root privileges to install all the software.

I also ran into many problems with linking the include library for Eclipse CDT.

Can anyone help me with *installing Juno* in a way that I do not need root access every time I change configurations in Eclipse?

Comment: I've updated the [guide](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/07/install-eclipse-juno-and-android-sdk-on-ubuntu/) to clarify that you shouldn't run Eclipse as root while updating packages (or under most circumstances). If you install Eclipse as root, `chown -R` Eclipse's folder and then run Eclipse as yourself/a normal user, your installed packages should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### How to install Eclipse Juno WITHOUT the need to change permissions

1. First, remove all previous versions of Eclipse.  If you would like: save your `/workspace` directory (cut and post the entire directory into your `~/`
2. Download [Eclipse from their official website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (I used "eclipse-mobile-juno-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz") 
   *But like was stated earlier, make sure that you have 32 and/or 64 bit versions of java available to match your Eclipse install. (I have BOTH openjdk-6 and -7-jre installed from **Synaptic Package Manager**)*

   - You can add package pieces later if the eclipse-mobile installation doesn't contain everything you want. For example, [**Linux Tools** here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/PluginInstallHelp).
   - Other package instructions are available from the download page, via the links on the left.
3. To avoid permissions issues, I unpacked it to `~/bin` and **archive manager** put Eclipse into its own 'eclipse' subdirectory there.
4. [Download the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), **and so that future upgrades of Eclipse and Ubuntu don't break it**, unpack it to `~/bin/eclipse/dropins`.
5. Developer.android.com instructs you to:

   > On Mac or Linux, open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory
   >   in the Android SDK, then execute **android sdk**.
6. However, when I downloaded the linux version of Android SDK, *there was no file "android sdk."*
7. Instead, navigate to to the tools path (in my case `~/bin/eclipse/dropins/android-sdk-linux/tools`) and [right-click] on "android" to change its properties to executable.
   [image: android file properties dialog: permissions tab]
8. Now you can double-click to run android, and download the packages you like.

   - Since everything is in your home directory, you don't need to modify your PATH environment variable (as per the developer instructions).
9. Download and install the ADT plugin from *http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html* [as per the normal instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

   - Configure the plugin with the path used, in this example `/home/clayton/bin/eclipse/dropins/android-sdk-linux`
   - If you want to install more packages from step-8 after step-9, from the Eclipse drop-down menu choose `Window > Android SDK Manager`
10. Navigate to `~/bin/eclipse` and make sure you mark "eclipse" as executable as well *(see step 7 for a refresher)*. [Right-click] and [Make link].  Move this shortcut to the desktop.

    - I went to the extra step of changing the icon for eclipse to the provided "icon.xpm" in the same subdirectory.
11. From step 1, move your "workspace" directory...or don't.  But specify it as your application workspace in the dialog and you'll be able to import any existing projects with ease *(those instructions would be for a different Q&A).*

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to use your downloaded file with the Ubuntu Software Center since it needs prepackaged files matching your Ubuntu version.

However, the current version of Eclipse in Ubuntu is 3.7.2. If you want to use the current one (4.2), you have to install it manually.

To see how this is done, please see [Eclipse Juno, need root access everytime I change the configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186299/install-eclipse-juno-on-12-04).

Comment: @maythux I think you misunderstood the initial question. The user clearly states that he does not want to install Eclipse manually but how to use the USC with his existing download. If however he decides to install manually anyway, all information he needs is provided in the link "Install Eclipse Juno on 12.04".

Answer (score 2):

Silly question, but... did you run the following, as stated in the link you posted?

```
chown -R USER:USER eclipse
```

This would allow you to run eclipse as USER and make configuration changes.

You can verify that all files in the installed directory are owned by USER by doing a search of the entire install directory (/opt/eclipse)

```
find /opt/eclipse/ | xargs ls -ld | grep -v USER
```

This shouldn't return anything if everything is owned by USER

Answer (score 1):

I referred to this [guide](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/07/install-eclipse-juno-and-android-sdk-on-ubuntu/).

I recommend that you follow this guide to installing juno and android sdk rather than the Android Developer website's.  it's thorough and quick.

The only downside is that you have to refer to your /opt directory and use the terminal to invoke eclipse. In other words, there isn't a physical button for Ubuntu just yet.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install it just run it:

> tar -xvf eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz
>
> cd eclip
>
> chmod +x eclipse
>
> ./eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Eclipse in following manner:

1. Remove current installation:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge eclipse*
   ```
2. Install eclipse again with CDT

   ```
   sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-CDT
   ```

   After that remove, `.eclipse` folder from your home directory and run Eclipse and check your C/C++ project.

Comment: I agree with you on that but the eclipse version that gets installed through Ubuntu's Repositories is Indigo. And I want to install Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow misnoticed that :(

Answer (score 0):

Download the archive from the official website, unzip it in /opt/eclipse/ (or your preferred directory), and run the installer.

Comment: I dont mean to be rude but that is what was mentioned in [link](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/07/install-eclipse-juno-and-android-sdk-on-ubuntu/) in my original post. And it did not work for me somehow.

Answer (score -3):

Generally, these contains source files and as far as I know you'll have to manually install them using the commands.

> > > > #### Ubuntu software center can install only packaged files(i.e ".deb").
> > > >
> > > > #### Ubuntu software center can't install the source files that you have mentioned.

Comment: make install need root previlege

Comment: @linuxandunix it cannot be done like this... you have to just run the eclipse binary ie. In terminal : ./eclipse

Comment: @PranitBauva : I was just giving a general example of installing source files. I hadn't actually checked the contents of the mentioned .tar.gz file.