# installing of eclipse on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Eclipse Juno on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186299/install-eclipse-juno-on-12-04)

I have downloaded `eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz` from eclipse site.

I want to use this downloaded file with ubuntu software center so that I need not to download all the data again if I install eclipse with ubuntu software center.

I don't want to manually install it.

thanks in advance