# How do I run eclipse as sudo

Tags: 12.04, sudo, eclipse

I've read that it's bad to run gui applications from a terminal using `sudo`.

In order to administer some eclipse updates, I need elevated privileges (view screenshot). 
**How do I do this correctly?**

[image]

Comment: Use portable version of eclipse to avoid permission issues

Comment: I am administering the update as the admin user. The changes I make will affect 2 other user accounts. Is this the same with the portable version?

Comment: Yes it's bad, and you use `gksu`

Comment: Thanks @UriHerrera Want to post that as the answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Eclipse's "Check for updates" not work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125722/why-does-eclipses-check-for-updates-not-work)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To run GUI applications as `root` you should not be using `sudo`, but instead use `gksu`.
In this particular case run `gksu eclipse`, then enter your password.

Comment: For KDE like kubuntu, use `kdesu` instead of `gksu`. For example press `[ALT] + [F2]` and type `kdesu eclipse`

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, you're forced to `sudo eclipse` because you did it once out of desperation, which changed some config file as root, and permanently rooted you in Sudoland for Eclipse. You can try:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx ~/workspace 
sudo chmod -R a+rwx ~/.eclipse
```

that got me out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the Eclipse update system does not work well when repackaged for various operating system packages.  If "apt-get upgrade" does not work for you, then I would suggest you stay away from the packaged version of Eclipse, and simply download the one you need directly from Eclipse, unpack and run it.

Then you can update it as needed.