# Where to unpack the android studio file?

Tags: software-installation, android-studio

I am new to Ubuntu, I have just installed dual boot Ubuntu 12.04. I want to install android studio, but I don't really know how. I have downloaded the android-studio-bundle.tgz file and in the it is written to unpack the file in the appropriate location. I don't really know what appropriate location for my applications means. Can you please tell me where to unpack this file, or if this is the correct way of installing android studio? 
also if you comment me a good guide or place to read about tips on ubuntu I would be very grateful, just to have general understanding of ubuntu.

main question: where should I unpack my android-studio-bundle.tgz file?

Comment: just unpack them to your home directory as long as java path is visible.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu It's not about what I tried and didn't work, It's about what is the best place to put it. What is the right way to do it, because I don't how ubuntu works and what consequences things will have.

Comment: I usually install software like this in my home folder ~/.local/lib

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The key parts of the question as I see them: user is new to Ubuntu/Linux, user wants a recommendation based off of best practices and basic user experience.

@luis-de-sousa was correct in pointing out the Ubuntu directory structure, but I used [this reference from Official Sources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview).

If you want *android-studio* to be available to all users (based on the above) **you should be unpacking the tar/tgz/zip to `/opt`** rather than the `/usr/local` or `/usr/bin` (with the latter being preferred for specific-user installations).  Setup properly, we shouldn't need to change user group permissions or any other high-level administration.

1. Unpack the downloaded tar/tgz/zip file where it lays
2. Using a Terminal window, navigate to that folder location (probably `cd ~/Downloads`), invoke `sudo -i` (You will need administrator/su permissions for the next few steps)
3. `mv android-studio /opt` moves the files you unpacked (requires permissions)
4. `gedit android-studio.desktop` this opens a text editor so that we may create a shortcut icon to open your new program.  **Insert the following code, then save the .desktop file.**

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
    Name=Android Studio
    Comment=Integerated Development Environment for Android
    Exec=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
    Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
    Terminal=false
    Type=Application
    Categories=Development;IDE
   ```
5. To finish up, `desktop-file-install android-studio.desktop`

We are done with the terminal window, you can close it or `exit`  That .desktop file now allows you to search for and find android-studio within Ubuntu's Unity interface (or whatever DE menu/dash you are using).  *In other words, click that icon in the upper-left to search for android-studio*  You may also *right-click* on the icon while it is running and "lock it to the launcher."

You can also create menu options to appear for your application launcher, [see the Ubuntu Documentation on Unity Launchers.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

---

Besides the in-text citations, I also referenced the following pages extensively:

http://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/ubuntu-13-04-adding-launchers-to-unity-panel/

[How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Installing

Comment: Thank you very much Clayton. That was the perfect and user friendliest solution I could ask for.

Comment: Well done. This is a perfect description on how to install manually.

Comment: For anyone stressing about where they should be creating `android-studio.desktop`, don't worry. The `desktop-file-install` step creates a new version of this file in `/usr/share/applications` so the one you create yourself ultimately becomes extraneous.

Comment: I just need to add a trailing semicolon after the last line: `Categories=Development;IDE` and `sudo` the step 5: `sudo desktop-file-install android-studio.desktop`

Answer (score 11):

In Linux, programmes are usually stored in `/usr/local` or `/usr/share`; when you install a programme with `apt` it is automatically set up inside one of these folders. I would advise you to create a folder like `/usr/local/android-studio` and unpack the file there (note that you'll need *sudo* rights to do it).

Otherwise you can unpack it somewhere in your `home` folder, also an option if you do not have *sudo* rights. Here it does not really matter where, you may create a folder like `~/software/android-studio` for convenience.

Read more about the [Linux directory structure](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/).

Comment: how can the user run something in `/usr/local/android-studio/bin`?

Comment: `./usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

Comment: Cautionary note: if you install such that a sudo is required for running, it might lead to the following problem when using the emulator: .ini files being created in /root and not visible to Android Studio. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829620/android-studio-avd-manager-creating-avds-in-root-directory

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let me state clear, there's an appropriated place to place stuff, but in this case, simple is the best, so I prefer any location where you already have write/read permissions, like you `$HOME` directory.

Take from [the instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Installing)

> ### Linux:
>
> 1. Unpack the downloaded Tar file, android-studio-bundle-.tgz, into an appropriate location for your applications.
> 2. To launch Android Studio, navigate to the android-studio/bin/ directory in a terminal and execute studio.sh.
> 3. You may want to add android-studio/bin/ to your PATH environmental variable so that you can start Android Studio from any directory.

Resuming in easy steps:

```
mkdir ~/android-sdk && cd ~/android-sdk
wget http://dl.google.com/android/studio/install/0.4.2/android-studio-bundle-133.970939-linux.tgz
tar xf android-studio-bundle-133.970939-linux.tgz
export PATH="~/android-sdk/android-studio/bin/:$PATH"
studio.sh
```

If you want to make them permanent:

```
echo 'export PATH="~/android-sdk/android-studio/bin/:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

or `.zshrc`. Depending the shell you use. Done. **You can use whatever path you like, just try to do not interfere with other software.**

Comment: Anyone knows where it's wrong?

Comment: I think (not sure, as I chose to abstain from voting in this case) because `~/android-sdk` is not an appropriate location for applications. Personally, I keep in `~` documents, pictures, music, videos and stuff like these.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu the path doesn't matter, that was the point of my answer. You can change the path to whatever you like. Also, it follows the wiki entry. If you check the other answer it also installs in HOME, so I don't know why is mine wrong?

Comment: OK, then add this to your answer, don't tell just to me... I don't see that point.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I was asking what was wrong, you gave your opinion, and I said that it shouldn't matter if that was the reason why people downvoted.

Comment: Can you give a good documentation on .bash_profile ,.profile, .bashrc and similar files

Comment: @Creator `man bash`

Comment: @Braiam - I am getting following error message when i log into shell as a user or root                                                                                                                         `bash: export: =': not a valid identifier
bash: export: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:~/android-studio/bin': not a valid identifier`         After I append .bashrc file with export string

Comment: @Creator I really don't know what you did, ask a new question with the entire content of your `.bashrc` file.