# Android studio only starts with sudo

Tags: permissions, android, chmod, android-studio, android-sdk

I just installed Android Studio, but I can only start it with root permissions: `sudo ./studio.sh` otherwise it fails with `Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main`

I am not sure where to start investigating the file permissions, any ideas?

Some info:

[image]

```
d@d-Aspire-M5-581TG /opt/android-studio/bin $ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.1
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rebecca
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
...

d@d-Aspire-M5-581TG ~ $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Update: I created a [desktop bookmark](https://askubuntu.com/a/449894/331972) and with that it launches ok, so it's not an issue anymore. Yet, It would be great to know why it doesn't work when I try it from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

After starting Android studio with `sudo`, select <kbd>Tools</kbd> - <kbd>Create Desktop Entry</kbd>.

This will create an icon for Android studio and if you do a search in the dash, it will pop up in-between the other applications.

Comment: I did this but it does not create a desktop entry for me.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Android Studio, too, and for me, every single file in /bin belongs to me and not to root. Maybe try changing that with `chown` and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

The file `/opt/android-studio/lib/bootstrap.jar` has the wrong permissions.

Fix this with the following command:

```
sudo chmod g+r,o+r /opt/android-studio/lib/bootstrap.jar
```

The above will give read attributes to "group" and "other".  Now you can use *Android Studio* as a normal user. Unless there are other incorrect permissions.

Answer (score 0):

what I did is:

1. `sudo mousepad`: to create a root owned shell file to launch it as root from GUI
2. save a .sh file with this command: `gksudo android-studio` for instance save it in `/home/YOUR_USER/studio.sh`
3. `sudo chmod 775 /home/luca/studio.sh`: allow execution of it
4. settings -> menu edit add an entry in the menu, with the command:  `/home/YOUR_USER/studio.sh`

done.

the advantage is that it didn't open a terminal to work an is very simple