# Some error messages displayed when I start terminal (both as root and as normal user)

Tags: command-line, bash, 14.10, environment-variables

I recently installed Android Studio , and to make the changes permanent I changed the PATH environment variable in .bashrc file, as shown in Second answer of  [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421389/where-to-unpack-the-android-studio-file/421424?noredirect=1#comment815595_421424).

I get following error messages or warning sort of things every time I launch a new terminal window.

`bash: export: '=': not a valid identifier`

bash: export: 
/home/android-studio/bin/:/usr/games:/home/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:
~/android-studio/bin': not a valid identifier`

This is what I did 
I opened .bashrc file using following command

`nano .bashrc`

then added following lines to .bashrc file.

`export PATH = "$PATH:~/android-studio/bin"`

Following is value in my path Variable

```
bash: /home/android-studio/bin: Is a directory
```

Comment: What is given when you run `echo $PATH`, and what line did you add to your `.bashrc` file? And did you run the `echo 'export PATH="~/android-sdk/android-studio/bin/:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc` command? You many need to run `source ~/.bashrc` or login/logout after making chanes to the `~/.bashrc file` (may not be a good idea if it is broken though)

Comment: Could you add output of this command to question: `grep "export" ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove spaces between = sign. 
It should look like:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/android-studio/bin"
```

not

```
export PATH = "$PATH:~/android-studio/bin"
```

Comment: So linux is whitespace sensitive as well?? It works thanx

Comment: @Creator not Linux, but bash is sensitive to spaces

Comment: Can I suggest using `"$PATH:$HOME/android-studio/bin"` (since `~` doesn't get expanded withing double-quotes)?

Comment: Yes that would work too